# Ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ implies $1=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $f$ be an ring homomorphism from $R_1$  to $R_2$ and define $f^*$ as the homomorphism from the group of units of $R_1$ to the group of units of $R_2$. Suppose $f^*$ is surjective, the question is to decide if this implies that $f$ is surjective.

After several attempts I got to this example. Take $R_1 =\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ (so integers mod 8), $R_2 = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, and define $f(x) = x \mod 5$ for every $x \in Z/8Z$.

Now I noticed something weird:
$$1 = f(1) = f(5\cdot 5 \mod 8) = f(5)\cdot f(5) = (5 \mod 5)\cdot (5 \mod 5) = 0\cdot 0 = 0$$

What is wrong with my map? I don't get it, everything seems to be correct. I've checked whether $f$ is a ring homomorphism and it is (altough I'm not so sure anymore). I can't think of other mistake, but there has to be one of course.

Comment: $(5,8)= 1\,\Rightarrow\,5\,$ is a unit in $\,\Bbb Z/8,\,$ indeed $\,5^2\equiv 1\pmod 8.\ $ Since a unit divides every element, every element is $\equiv 0\,$ in a ring modulo a unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problems begin here:

> $f(x) = x \mod 5$

If $x$ is an integer, we could understand what you mean by this. But $x$ isn't an integer here: it's an element of $\mathbf{Z} / 8 \mathbf{Z}$. What could "$x \mod 5$" mean for an *integer modulo $8$*?

Now, what you were probably trying to do is use the fact that every homomorphism $R/I \to S$ can be (uniquely) specified by giving a homomorphism $f : R \to S$ with the property that $f(i) = 0$ for all $i \in I$.

So, $f(x) = x \mod 5$ would make sense... *if* $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in 8 \mathbf{Z}$. But, alas, $f(x) = 0$ is not true for all $x \in 8 \mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

The map that you have defined isn't even a homomorphism. In fact, if $m, n$ are coprime, then the only homomorphism between $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ is the trivial one, sending everything to 0: $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: (and even *that* isn't a ring homomorphism, if you use the definition of "ring" that includes $1$ as part of its structure)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $\mathcal{O}^{(*)}(a) < \infty$ then there is an homomorphism $f: \langle a\rangle \to G$ such that $f(a) = b$ if, and only if, $\mathcal{O}(b)$ divides $\mathcal {O}(a)$.

$(*)$ here $\mathcal{O}(a)$ means the order of the element $a$.

So if $G = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} = \langle \overline{1}\rangle$ and $\mathcal{G} = \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} = \{\overline{1},\overline{2},\ldots,\overline{7}\}$ the only element $b$ in $\mathcal{G}$  whose order divides $\mathcal{O}(a) = 5$ is $\overline{0}$ which means that

$$\begin{align}f: \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}\\\overline{n} &\mapsto \overline{0}\end{align} $$

and the trivial homomorphism is the only homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

A little more simply: if $f(x)=x$ were an additive function, then $0+5\Bbb Z= f(0+8\Bbb Z)=f(5+8\Bbb Z)+f(3+8\Bbb Z)=5+5\Bbb Z + 3+5\Bbb Z=3+5\Bbb Z$.

Since this says that $0+8\Bbb Z$ has two distinct images under the proposed mapping, we have a contradiction with the well-definedness of the "function." So, it can't be a function at all, much less a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x$ is not even well-defined function, least homomorphism, if we interpret it in suitable sense $f([x]) = [x]$ since $[1] = [9]$ in $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ and we have $f([1]) = [1]$, $f([9]) = [9]$, but $[1]\neq [9]$ in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. When dealing with quotient sets, always remember to check if your wanna-be function (relation, to be precise) is independent of choice of representatives. That's why homomorphism and isomorphism theorems are so valuable in algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}f\colon\Z/8\Z\to\Z/5\Z$ is a ring homomorphism.

Then $f\circ \pi\colon \Z\to \Z/5\Z$ is a ring homomorphism, where $\pi\colon\Z\to\Z/8\Z$ is the canonical projection. But there's only one homomorphism of unital rings $\Z\to \Z/5\Z$ and its kernel is $5\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $\ker(f\circ\pi)\supseteq(8\Z+5\Z)=\Z$. A contradiction.

If you don't require ring homomorphisms are unital, the map $g=f\circ\pi$ is still determined by the image of $1$. Then $g(5)=5g(1)=0$, so again $\ker g\supseteq 5\mathbb{Z}$. The fact that $\ker g\supseteq 8\Z$ is obvious by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that hasn't been listed yet.

Let $k * n$ abbreviate $n + n + \cdots + n$ with $k$ summands.

Let $f$ be an arbitrary homomorphism $f : R \to S$.

1. $f(0)$ this is the expression we start out with,
2. $f(16 * 1)$ exploiting the fact that $8 * 1$ is $0$ in $R$.
3. $f(5 * 1 + 5 * 1 + 5 * 1 + 1)$ rearranging the sum slightly.
4. $f(5 * 1) + f(5 * 1) + f(5 * 1) + f(1)$
5. $5*f(1) + 5*f(1) + 5*f(1) + f(1) $
6. $0+f(1)$
7. $f(1)$

Thus $f(0) = f(1)$ for any possible homomorphism.

---

I think your map is intended to be the following, defined by applying *mod $5$* to the canonical representative of each equivalence class. As others have pointed out, this map is not well-defined when your definition is applied to the integers in the equivalence class themselves, rather than to the canonical representatives alone.

1. $f(0) = 0$
2. $f(1) = 1$
3. $f(2) = 2$
4. $f(3) = 3$
5. $f(4) = 4$
6. $f(5) = 0$
7. $f(6) = 1$
8. $f(7) = 2$

This map is not a homomorphism. For example $f(-1) = f(7) = 2$ BUT $-f(1) = -1 = 4$, so this map does not respect negation, one of the requirements for being a homomorphism.